# i want to convert my numeric value to text in excel. ex:In A1 cell have "2" then convert to that value "Two"

Tags: text, numbers, excel-2010

I want to convert my numeric value to text in excel.
For example:In A1 cell have "2" then convert to that value "Two"

Please help me ...

Comment: What is the range of values you are trying to convert??

Comment: probable duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085300/how-to-convert-excel-numeric-cell-value-into-words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have numerals **0** thru **9** on **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=CHOOSE(A1+1,"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine")
```

This formula is only good for single numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gary, sorry for the delay, Its the 6 digit number

Comment: Thank u so much, i get answer for your given link again thank you so much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085300/how-to-convert-excel-numeric-cell-value-into-words